# Как скрыть / показать блок лендинга из админки WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

Задача такая есть лендинг на WP нужно показывать скрывать нужные блоки. Тоесть в админке сделать раздел с чекбоксами. Поставил чекбокс в админке на сайте отабразился блок который привязан к чекбоксу и наоборот.  пробовал сделать через add_action( '', '' ) И ACF что-то не выходит... Подскажите как можно реализовать..

Answer (score 0):

В коде главной странице получаешь массив из чекбоксов. Допустим $cheks
После, в коде страницы нужные блоки оборачиваешь в конструкцию:

```
if ($cheks[0] == true) { ?>
    <div>...</div>
<? } ?>
```

Так для нужных блоков